# Why did Tyler yell at Mackenzie?

Tags: analysis, 13-reasons-why

In S2E10, Tyler inexplicably yells at Mackenzie and tells her she's boring. It appeared to me that he was making sure Cyrus' friends saw him do it but I don't understand what his motivation was and am wondering if I missed something.

Comment: Tyler yells at Mackenzie more than once.. the first time is at school [at his locker], and the second time is at punk concert. In both cases though, the reason for him yelling and being upset is because he was trying to cover up the embarrassment of what happened to him during their date at the movies.

Answer (score 2):

Tyler had prematurely ejaculated while kissing Mackenzie in the movie theater and this news got circulated in the school, so this was the Tyler's way of responding in his defense.

Comment: No that happened after the yelling. I rewatched it again and I guess I'd missed the part where she said "it's totally natural" which explains why he freaked out.

Comment: @heath3n then I will rewatch that scene and update answer later

Comment: @heath3n having seen series 2 twice now, i can safely say that no, the cinema scene didnt happen after the yelling. The argument was in episode 10 whereas the cinema scene was episode 8 or 9

Comment: Yeah I meant the circulation happened after the yelling.